# How to manage groups and users in Jenkins

Tags: ldap, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to use role based security plugin in Jenkins, but i'm not sue i am using it right.

I've decided to go with jenkin's own user database as a security realm instead of LDAP. i'm adding the users one by one.

Now in the Assign Roles screen, i have global roles like administrator, read only etc... and i have project specific roles like prod_a_developer, prod_b_developer...

For each user, do i have to both assign one of the global roles for him and also assign a specific project role ?

Also, how do i assign a user to a group ? instead of assigning each user a global role i want to assign a group a global role.

not so trivial,

Can someone please help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently upgraded the [WIKI description](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin):

> Global Roles override anything you specify in the Project Roles. That
>   is, when you give a role the right to Job-Read in the Global Roles,
>   then this role is allowed to read all Jobs, no matter what you specify
>   in the Project Roles.
>
> It may therefore be advisable to leave most (all) options unchecked in
>   Job, Run and SCM in the Global Roles section for normal users.

In a recent [message on the jenkins-users list](http://groups.google.com/group/jenkinsci-users/msg/a8712462df9ea86f?hl=en), user Romain writes:

> We do the following:
>
> - 3 main global roles, admin, job-creator, and anonymous.
> - 1 project role per set of jobs to "segregate" from others.
> - Users with job-creator role know the pattern of the name of the jobs
>     they can create and are aware that, if they don't comply with it, they
>     will need to ask the admin to rename the job or grant them new rights.